# problem with cvxopt on mac //incompatible architecture

Tags: python, macos, cvxopt

I need `cvxopt` to run some portfolio optimization scripts. I have a MacBook pro with an M1 chip running `Monterey 12.3, Python 3.10.2` and `pip 22.0.4`.
I installed `cvxopt` with `pip`, also installed Rosetta2 but I keep getting the following message:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxopt/base.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxopt/base.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

Could someone help?
I am quite new to programming and only recently moved to Mac which I am still getting to grips with.
Thanks!

I read all the threads I could find, installed Rosetta2 manually, checked the version of python and pip I had but everything seems fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Building `cvxopt` from source with `pip install --no-binary cvxopt cvxopt` solved this problem for me.